# how do i fit images from an api call?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My first time posting anything here so if i am missing something please tell me! Ok, so my problem is that the images in my categories page don't fit eachother and does not align anymore. This happened after I learned a little javascript and got the images from an API call. Now they don't look so good anymore... especially in mobile view. How can I make it so they are all the same size? I'm totally a rookie by the way.
Here is the link to my page: https://lovely-croissant-3cceca.netlify.app/

I tried fixing it with CSS but it doesn't "react" anymore when I change something. The mobile view in the categories page, the images are to high. But wwhen I try to lower them in the media queries the desktop version also changes. I know it likely something with the  i made when I was trying out javascript. I also cant change the name "test" to something else, because the everything gets disturbed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output's what matters, not the fact that the images are called through API, we can address the result with CSS.

The film titles push the images down, because they are in the same container, so we have to give them a hight.

The ratio of the images differs, so you could use `object-fit: cover` to crop the images at a maximum size of the smallest image's height.

On mobile: you need the `overflow` to be set to `visible`, and take out the `padding` from the `.container-child` too (there are multiple extra spaces otherwise), and add only to the parent.

Something like this, would do it:

```
    .container-child p {
       height: 50px;
       text-align: center;
       display: block;
   }
    /*from here the responsive code*/
    @media (max-width:1624px){
        .container-child img {
          object-fit: cover;
          max-width: 500px;
          max-height: 709px; /*the smallest image*/
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
        }
    }
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
    .container-child {
        padding-top: 0em; 
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
       }
       #test {
        margin-top: 130px;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center
       }
       html, body {
        overflow: visible;
        background: #000;
       }
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! How do I make the images the same size when they come from an API?

Comment: I've updated my answer, take another look. Thank you.